# Retrieve all columns in row with min date?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, min

Is there a way to solve something like this, without using a self join?  Some way to use the min() function?

I want to get the first fruit entry for each group of columns c1 and c2.  (Assume dates cannot be identical)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;
CREATE TABLE test
(
    c1 varchar(25),
    c2 varchar(25),
    fruit varchar(25),
    currentTime Datetime
);
INSERT INTO test VALUES    
('a','b','pineapple','2013-01-28 20:50:00'),
('a','b','papaya','2013-01-28 20:49:00'),
('a','b','pear','2013-01-28 20:51:00'),
('a','c','peach','2013-01-28 18:12:00'),    
('a','c','plum','2013-01-28 20:40:00'),
('a','c','pluot','2013-01-28 16:50:00');
```

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT t2.* 
  FROM (SELECT c1,
               c2,
               MIN(currentTime) AS ct
          FROM test 
      GROUP BY c1, c2) as t1
  JOIN test t2
    ON t1.c1 = t2.c1 AND
       t1.c2 = t2.c2 AND
       t2.currentTime = t1.ct
```

This yields the earliest entry for each `c1/c2` pair, but is there a way to use `min()` and avoid the self join?

Comment: I don't think you can archive this with only MIN without any joins/sub queries as MIN does not work in conjunction with the rest of query so the result of min is from itself and does not affect the rest of the query itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is "yes".  You can do it with just aggregation.  The key is to use the `group_concat()`/`substring_index()` trick to get the first fruit:

```
select c1, c2,
       substring_index(group_concat(fruit order by currentTime), ',', 1) as fruit,
       min(currentTime)
from test
group by c1, c2;
```

This has been tested on your SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Wow, never even heard of that one.  Pretty sweet, and easier syntax. Thank you for that.  Would up vote you, but need a little more reputation.

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT c1,
         c2,
         currentTime AS ct
    FROM test
GROUP BY c1,c2 
HAVING MIN(ct)
```

Or, if you would like to get the `fruit` column as well, try:

```
  SELECT c1,
         c2,
         fruit,
         currentTime AS ct
    FROM test
GROUP BY c1,c2 
HAVING MIN(ct)
```

Comment: I'd like to get the 'fruit', column too.  This doesn't seem to work when you include that column.  I couldn't figure out a way around it.

Comment: `| a    | b    | papaya | 2013-01-28 20:49:00 |
| a    | c    | pluot  | 2013-01-28 16:50:00 |`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood you right but:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM test 
 WHERE currentTime IN (SELECT MIN(currentTime) FROM test)
```

Comment: The OP asked for a solution without a "self join" - your answer has a subquery which references the original table - essentially a join.

Answer (score -1):

How about this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    test
ORDER BY
    currentTime
LIMIT
    1;
```

Would this work for your purposes?